# identify common chars in correct order (kind of regular expression) from a array of strings

Tags: string, design-patterns

I am looking for how to identify common chars from a set of strings of different
 length. First let me tell the same problem had posted here, and the author is somehow able to find out the answer. But i could not get his solution. I tried to post my query over 
there, but not sure whether I will get any reply. So i am posting as a new one. (this is 
the link for old qs [Find common chars in array of strings, in the right order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2161237/find-common-chars-in-array-)
of-strings-in-the-right-order).

I m taking the same example from him.

Let's assume "+" is the "wildcard char":

Array(
0 => '48ca135e0$5',
1 => 'b8ca136a0$5',
2 => 'c48ca13730$5',
3 => '48ca137a0$5');

Should return :

$wildcard='+8ca13+0$5';

This looks to me as a standard problem. so i doubt there will be some library 
for this. If not pls show some light for solving this.

I dont think comparing char-by-char work (as told in the reply), becoz the matching char can come in anywhere (eg:- arr1[1] and arr2[3] can be starting index of matching some substring and the other way also).

regards,

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're looking for the "longest common substring". The first longest common substring is 8ca13, the second longest is 0$5. Once we have these two strings, you can take any of the strings in the set and replace extra characters with a single +.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_substring_problem